# How to recover an emptied file in Remix

Tags: remix

I am using Remix IDE on Chrome browser for developing smart contracts.

Today during working on a file when I changed program tab and returned to it again, I found that all of the file contents has been deleted automatically. No Ctrl+Z, close and reopen and other tricks was useful.

1- Can anyone help me recover the emptied file?

2- Does Remix have any limitation in file size?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no solution for this problem.

I have lost some of my important Solidity program files in both Chrome and Firefox.

Finally I decided to use `remixd` service as a localhost server and use store my Solidity programs in my local file system.

Answer (score 3):

All Remix files are stored in your browser's local storage. So there is no file size limitation coming from Remix.
If you want to check the storage for lost files, check out [this link](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/25648/where-solidity-files-are-stored-in-remix-ide)  to learn how to back up or restore local storage files. if you don't find any files there, I'm afraid all of your files are gone.

Next time you use remix, make sure you have a backup of your files. You can also publish all explorer files to Github gist. Check out [this documentation](https://remix.readthedocs.io/en/stable/file_explorer.html#connect-your-filesystem-to-remix) to see how

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation. All of my work from the past year disappeared from the `Remix IDE` interface. However, I was able to recover them through the raw IndexedDB files from Google Chrome. I wrote a script that allows me to save all existing contracts from IndexedDB without other metadata: https://github.com/0xcodefive/RestoreSolidityDB